# Zed graph graphpane- change the color of the axis

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graph, zedgraph

i am trying to create a graph with zedgraph. I have already changed the color of everything. But I can't change the color of the black lines.They should be also white. Could someone help me? there have to be a solution

Best regards 
Laoleo

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJMMa.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

With GraphPane you can access properties YAxis, Y2Axis, YAxisList and Y2AxisList. Colors for the axis may be changed as follows :

```
var col = Color.Blue; 
foreach (var y in myGraphPane.Y2AxisList)
{
    y.Color = col;
    y.Scale.FontSpec.FontColor = col;
    y.MajorTic.Color = col;
    y.MinorTic.Color = col;
}
```

And similar for the x-axis'.

See also [Zedgraph documentation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20documentation/5.1.0%20%2B%204.6.0/).